# Product Lookup throws generic SQL Error

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have upgraded an On-Prem CRM from 2011 to 2016. Earlier it was accessible only from company network now it is available on the internet(no adfs)using SSL
Problem is that whenever you try to add a Line item by typing a name and clicking on the search icon in the lookup control, it throws a generic SQL Server error.

If you simply scroll without typing anything it works fine. Same thing happened when I tried to add product to the Orders.

This is not happening for any other entity.
The same problem occurs on the upgraded 
organization as well as the trial organization created during Install

[image]

[image]

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Generic SQL error.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/.../Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147204784</ErrorCode>

  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="schemas.datacontract.org/.../System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Generic SQL error.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2016-09-30T11:59:21.4443823Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately "SQL Generic error" doesn't give any explanation what's going wrong with your CRM. To get detailed explanation turn on trace - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907490, restart IIS, reproduce an error and open Trace folder to get trace file from it. It will have detailed explanation what's wrong with your instance. If it would not be clear for you what's wrong feel free to update this thread with new details.